# Removing/Copying multiple files with Python

Tags: python, file

I use `os.remove()` for deleting a file, and `shutil.copyfile()` for copying a file. Sometimes I need to remove/copy all the files in a directory, and I use the following code.

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(profilerPath + "/*.*"))

for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

It works fine, but I'd like to ask if you have better code for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about [`shutil.copytree()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) and [`shutil.rmtree()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)? They copy/delete recursivly, i.e. everything below a given path.

If you want to copy/delete files only, without traversing into subdirectories, your current solution is fine (though you should check if each file indeed is a file and not a directory -- directory names could also match the pattern `*.*`).